# Fantasy about three magical descendants/ children with different powers fighting with each other

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

Looking to find which book or series of books that center around three descendants of some powerful person, who take on human bodies and each have their special respective powers. The characters are part human with these ancient warring children's personalities and powers superimposed on them. Two are male, one is female. The protagonist male is named Alan, I believe, who is a traveler and can find his way through any tangled maze or impossible to navigate terrain.  His brother's name starts with a H, maybe Hadan or something, and has special powers with fire.  The sisters name I forget, but she has special powers with water.

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Do you have any hints about real world details, such as when you have read this and in what language, how old the book may be, writing style etc?

Comment: I read it between 2005-2008, in English, I"m guessing the book wasn't written before 1990 but i could be wrong.  I believe the book was written in third person omniscient, where you know the thoughts of pretty much all of the characters in the story.  One other thing is that the three main characters are very old and as a by-product of their power/magic, extend the lives of others who spend a lot of time with them.

Comment: It reminds me quite a bit of Roger Zelazny's Amber series (magical mazes navigated by superannuated quarreling siblings) as well as any number of Diana Wynne Jones books (Jones often returned to themes of dysfunctional family dynamics among people with magical powers) but it isn't close enough to either for me to make it an answer.  You might check those out, however.

Comment: The basic idea sounds like Jenny Nimmo's 'Children of the Red King' (warring children with different magical powers, descendants of some powerful person), but the details don't really match up.